# Lua Lanes linda

Tags: lua, lua-lanes

I have lanes set up and running just fine but I'm having trouble understanding the linda passing of values, I found this code on the lanes site:

```
  linda_h:set( key, [val] )
  [val]= linda_h:get( key )
```

If I do a set/get my application crashes so I'm wondering how I declare the table for set/get?

If I use it as a string then the set/get kind of works but will crash after a few runs of the lane:

```
 Stop = "0" --outside of lane
 -- start lane
 -- callback function in lane
 if linda_h:get( Stop ) == "1" then
  return 
 end
```

Does anyone have any pointers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is confusing, but I think you want to use the `:send` and `:receive` methods, not `:set` and `:get`.  Send and receive make the thing behave like an ordinary queue.  It seems that `:get` is like receive except it doesn't remove from the queue, but I'm not sure.  And I can't figure out `:set` at all.